# Is Software Development Process the same as Software Development Life Cycle?

Tags: lifecycle, software-design

I have been taking classes on Udacity for the course "Software Development Process".

In Lesson 1, A software process was defined as the process of breaking down software development into smaller pieces that can be tackled individually.
In lesson 2 however, the software development life cycle was introduced as a sequence of decisions that determine the history of the software.

However, when I googled for software development life cycle, it was defined as "The process of planning, creating, testing and deploying an information system"

and when I googled for the various software development processes and software development life cycle models, they were both almost the same.

This has got me a bit confused. Could you please tell me the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are similar but I'd say that in the real world, the "process" part is about the beginning of the life cycle.  Namely requirements, prototyping, design, construction etc.  In practice, when people talk about the life cycle they're also considering upgrades, maintenance, feature timelines, and eventually replacement.

"Process" has many flavors-du-jour like agile, scrum, waterfall, spiral, etc.  Life cycle places less emphasis on process and and more on path from inception to replacement/retirement of the product.

Process is tactical, life cycle (at its best) is strategic.

Comment: I like this answer because essentially the life cycle continues long after the initial product release.  If anything, it's a series of processes.

Comment: @Fhaab, excellent point!  In fact, many projects use one process to initially develop the software and switch into a different process for maintenance through its maturity phase.  This is especially true in my experience working in regulated industries.

Answer (score 0):

They are almost the same thing.  The difference is really just one of emphasis.

The "life-cycle" is looking at software development from a descriptive perspective; i.e. "this is how software is developed".

The "process" is looking it from a more prescriptive perspective; i.e. "this is what people *should do* / *how they should do it* when developing software".

And to be honest, people often use the terms / viewpoints interchangeably.